# The data types in each column don't need to be compatible between the UNION queries

Tags: sql, union

I read [here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/union-attacks) that to be able to use SQL UNION queries,

> data types in each column must be compatible between the individual queries.

So `select a, b from table1 UNION select c, d from table2`, for this query to work, we need `a` and `c` data types to be compatible.

However, when I try to test that, and make table `users` having two columns `(id int, name varchar(15))`, and table `calc` having two values (x int, y int), and after inserting elements
(1, 'saad') into table `users`, and values (3, 5) into table `calc`, and try query `select * from users union select * from calc;`, it shows the results as follows without any errors:

```
1 |  saad
3 |  5
```

although `name` and `y` data types is not compatible, and was supposed to cause error
`Conversion failed when converting the int value 5 to data type varchar`

I thought it may be browser specific behavior, so I tried this also in google chrome, but it worked without any errors also!

Can someone explain to me why?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I'm using `MySql 5.6`

Comment: It depends on the database you are using.  Some databases are a bit more flexible on type compability.

Comment: usually int can be converted into varchar, but not vice versa

Comment: [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=650e1211535a2e5b8c01eeefadc111d9), [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cba858cbb7f210462da3bd5f952b83c) and [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2cba858cbb7f210462da3bd5f952b83c) will not allow that

Comment: @IłyaBursov I changed the query to `select * from calc union select * from users;` to make varchar be converted to int,  but nothing change. So it seams like two other comments said, that it depends on the database.

Comment: You did not mention which database you use.

Comment: @forpas I edited my answer

Comment: Mysql does implicit conversions, not only for UNION.

Answer (score 1):

With MS SQL, there's a distinction between UNION and UNION ALL.

In the case of a UNION query, each value is compared to every other value for that column across all of select clauses.  This might result in fewer records in final result than exist in the original select clause results.  Even if you didn't intend for it, the optimizer will compare values from a and c along with b and d to find the uinion of those two sets.  That also means that the datatype if they're different goes through an implicit data conversion to sql_variant to accomplish the goal of the union request.

Since UNION ALL is just stacking the sets one on top of each other, there's less of a need to compare the values.